# libMobileGestalt copySystemVersionDictionaryValue

Tags: ios, crash

My app goes crash after installed a new update from app store and sometime log says -

```
libMobileGestalt copySystemVersionDictionaryValue: Could not lookup ReleaseType from system version dictionary
```

Anyone familiar with it??

### one of the customer provided a log.

Jul 23 15:57:49 Ami-Sandlers-iPhone backboardd[26] : ALS: SetDisplayFactor: factor=0.0500
Jul 23 15:57:50 Ami-Sandlers-iPhone backboardd[26] : ALS: SetDisplayFactor: factor=1.0000
Jul 23 16:00:24 Ami-Sandlers-iPhone backboardd[26] : com.demandmedia.traileraddict.ios.free failed to resume in time
Jul 23 16:00:24 Ami-Sandlers-iPhone backboardd[26] : Forcing crash report of TrailerAddict[4919]...
Jul 23 16:00:24 Ami-Sandlers-iPhone backboardd[26] : Finished crash reporting.
Jul 23 16:00:24 Ami-Sandlers-iPhone com.apple.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:com.demandmedia.traileraddict.ios.free[0xeab9][4919]) : (UIKitApplication:com.demandmedia.traileraddict.ios.free[0xeab9]) Exited: Killed: 9
Jul 23 16:00:24 Ami-Sandlers-iPhone backboardd[26] : Application 'UIKitApplication:com.demandmedia.traileraddict.ios.free[0xeab9]' exited abnormally with signal 9: Killed: 9
Jul 23 16:00:24 Ami-Sandlers-iPhone ReportCrash[4925] : **libMobileGestalt copySystemVersionDictionaryValue: Could not lookup ReleaseType from system version dictionary**

### Jul 23 16:00:24 Ami-Sandlers-iPhone ReportCrash[4925] : Saved crashreport to /var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/TrailerAddict_2013-07-23-160024_Ami-Sandlers-iPhone.plist using uid: 0 gid: 0, synthetic_euid: 501 egid: 0

Comment: Please provide a symbolicated crash report. The posted console output does not indicate anything.